# Is it possible to change the URI dynamically on runtime in the filter?

Tags: kotlin, spring-cloud-gateway

Defining routes in the "yaml" file is pretty handy, and that makes our job easier until we come across defining multiple routes per URI.

Can the URI be changed in route by using filters?

I'm sharing an example of what our routing definitions look like.

```
    - id: route_uk
      uri: ${applications.downstream.uk.host}
      filters:
       - ...
      predicates:
        - Path=/todos/{id}
    - id: route_us
      uri: ${applications.downstream.us.host}
      filters:
       - ...
      predicates:
        - Path=/todos/{id}
    - id: route_eu
      uri: ${applications.downstream.eu.host}
      filters:
       - ...
      predicates:
        - Path=/todos/{id}
    - id: route_asia
      uri: ${applications.downstream.asia.host}
      filters:
       - ...
      predicates:
        - Path=/todos/{id}
```

For the sake of simplicity, we would like to have a single route with a dummy URI in yaml file and try to change it by using the incoming request's HTTP headers. Is there any functionality that Spring Cloud Gateway offers? Otherwise, we will end up with duplicated fragments in route definitions.

There is a [sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/276) about how to do it, but it is pretty old. I'm look for your suggestions.

Thanks a lot